# Automate Export to Layers without overwriting

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, batch-processing

Here is the problem. I have a folder of PNGs. For each PNG, I want to create multiple PNGs with different styles applied to them.

My approach was to create an action which creates multiple layers for each PNG. Different styles were applied to different layers and the then each layer was exported to PNG using, 'Scripts > Export Layers as Files. Since Export Layers as Files requires you add a prefix to exported files' filenames, when I use 'Automate > Batch' to apply action to all PNGs in folder, the files generated are overwritten.

I have being trying to find a solution to this problem but haven't gotten anywhere so far. [Automating Export Layers to Files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11459/automating-export-layers-to-files) is a similar problem but there isnt any valid answer.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!
Loveleen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automating Export Layers to Files](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11459/automating-export-layers-to-files)

Comment: I don't understand how _not_ adding a prefix to your files would help. However, you're welcome to try [this script](https://github.com/jwa107/Photoshop-Export-Layers-to-Files-Fast) as it just exports layers based on their name and doesn't require a prefix or suffix. Full disclosure, I am the original author of the linked script.

Comment: are you looking to rename the files between export? The problem is the world works like this: If you csn not find what you need off the shelf, then you need to build it. Due to the way our copyright works legally it usually means you need to do the e tire job from scratch.

Comment: Could Hazel help? Hazel can watch folders for new files, then process and move them. You could set up your exporting to a known location, then get Hazel to move and rename as you dump sets of images in. I use Hazel for something similar. https://www.noodlesoft.com

Answer (score 1):

When you use the automate batch with an action, if you don't want the files to be rewritten, you have the option to save them in a different folder that you previously created. Below the "destination" you can select the new folder to save your new files into. I guess you'll need to change the folder for each new batch.

You can also decide to add an extra digit or letter at the end of your file to prevent the overwriting.

In the "export layers as files", you can also select a destination.

I'm not sure to understand if this will solve your issue but I often use the automate/batch to rename files quickly. You can also use the "save as" command in your actions and make some tests with it.

[image: Automate resaving in Photoshop with an action, in a different folder to prevent overwriting]

[image: Script Save as Layers Files Photoshop new destination folder]